# Order object not iterable in python error in django

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def lobby(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    shippingddress=ShippingAddress.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    
    context={
        'order':order,
        'ship':shippingddress
    }

    return render(request,"lobby.html",context)
```

and this is my html:

```
    {% for ord in order %}
              <div class="single_confirmation_details">
                <h4>Order Info</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <p>Order Number</p><span>: {{ord.id}}</span>
                  </li>
</ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting this error:`'Order' object is not iterable`
I dont know why this error is coming. I have passed shippingaddress in context which is working fine but for Order it is showing error. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a *single order*, so it makes no sense to iterate over it.

In the template you thus should remove the <s>`{% for … %} … {% endfor %}`</s> loop:

```
<div class="single_confirmation_details">
    <h4>Order Info</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><p>Order Number</p><span>: {{ order.pk }}</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok it worked. But I think I have had earlier instances where even if a single object was there it worked using loop..Anyway..Thanks

Comment: @VATSALJAIN: normally that should not be the case. Note however that a `QuerySet` that contains one element, is not the same as that single element. So if you iterate over `MyModel.objects.filter(...)` and the filter condition matches one object, then this is a collection. But by using `.get`, or `.get_or_create(..)` you retrieve a single *object*.

Comment: Yes that was the case